# Greiner or Landau for Math major student?

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-question, education

For textbook series by Greiner or Landau, is it recommended to start reading for math major students, who have no serious physics background, but comfortable with maths ?

It seems that both Greiner and Landau are in same purpose to introduce most areas in a complete and rigorous way.

Is there a big difference between Greiner and Landau, in content and depth ? (Greiner is more new ?)

For personal purpose, I will work in applied mathematics

(in areas closely related to physics, that's why I need serious physics knowledge, particularly in classical/statistical/quantum mechanics, electrodynamics...),

rather than theoretical physics.

(thus something like particle physics, cosmology, string theory, quantum field theory ... might not be useful for me)

Comment: Based on my personal choices, I would go with Landau's series. Those books are classics of excellent scientific writing. Greiner's books aren't bad, but they do not come even close in terms of quality. Having said that, studying from just one set of books will leave you with significant gaps, even for the basics (and none of these textbook series contain anything more than the basics!). Physics is just too rich to be pressed into a standard textbook series. That's what the whole of the physics library is for. My best advice: use it!

Comment: Are you looking to *understand physical principles*, or are you looking to have *exposure to useful equations in physics*? These are different things.

Comment: Greiner is not free of misconceptions and not-so-implicit errors.

Answer (score 3):

The Landau series is less modern than many of the Griener books from the series, however its much more concise and of very high quality. If you are comfortable with the maths and just need *some* physics insight, Landau is a fantastic choice. If you want some more modern approaches with more thought put into application and examples, then the Greiner books offer that, as well as covering more topics as far as I know.

That being said, I am a big fan of the Landau series as they are very high quality and easy to get to grips with compared with many books. In the end, you probably want to consult multiple books - I never get on with just a single book, I tend to opt for a 'main' book to learn from, supplemented with others for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yeah, I agree that it is necessary to consult many resources, one of main purpose here is to select a "main" good resource for personal collection and serious study, then it is ok to use the library for filling the gaps.

Comment: Can I say that if I mainly consult this 2 series, then I do not really need to use like Goldstein, Jackson for "main-reading" anymore ? (Maybe just occasionally for some  pages in library) (And physics is not core research for me after all,  though it is important and often related for my research field)